# How to expand CSS DIVs to 100% width and centre after pushed down for mobile?

Tags: html, css

Recently I've been updating my site for mobile browsers and have come across a problem with DIV centering and widths.

Essentially I have an inline block of three boxes (DIVs), which sit inside a container DIV. Each of the three boxes adapts its width by a % and this works fine on desktop browsers but on mobile the boxes get pushed down below each other and remain left aligned with their minimum width unchanged (i.e. big blank space created on the right side).

However what I'd like to do is have the boxes become centre aligned when they're pushed down and for each of them to then expand their width to 100% of the container so as to use all the available container width.

```
<div style="width:50%;background-color:#dadada;padding:4px;border-radius:4px;overflow:hidden;">

    <div style="float:left;margin:auto;min-width:33%;">
        <div style="border: 1px solid #aeaefb;">
            <div style="width:95%;margin:auto;border: 3px solid #9a244f;">
                    Content goes into this box...
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div style="float:left;margin:auto;min-width:33%;">
        <div style="border: 1px solid #aeaefb;">
            <div style="width:95%;margin:auto;border: 3px solid #9a244f;">
                    Content goes into this box...
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div style="float:left;margin:auto;min-width:33%;">
        <div style="border: 1px solid #aeaefb;">
            <div style="width:95%;margin:auto;border: 3px solid #9a244f;">
                    Content goes into this box...
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Now I could use Media Queries to solve this (have it adopt float:none and some manual tweaking etc.) or jQuery but I feel like I'm overlooking something simple in vanilla CSS that could do it for both mobile and desktop browsers. Is there a way that's simple and as backwards compatible as possible?

Comment: For me either use a framework like Bootstrap or media queries

Comment: You could try an attempt with a combination of flex-box display

Comment: You must not use any inline style, it is a bad practice. and using inline css you cannot make things responsive. Use `Internal / External` css and use `media queries` to make responsive

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

I removed float:left from inner divs and made it display:inline-block.
Also added text-align:center to container.

```html
<div style="width:50%;background-color:#dadada;padding:4px;border-radius:4px;overflow:hidden;text-align:center">

    <div style="display:inline-block;margin:auto;min-width:33%;">
        <div style="border: 1px solid #aeaefb;">
            <div style="width:95%;margin:auto;border: 3px solid #9a244f;">
                    Content goes into this box...
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div style="display:inline-block;margin:auto;min-width:33%;">
        <div style="border: 1px solid #aeaefb;">
            <div style="width:95%;margin:auto;border: 3px solid #9a244f;">
                    Content goes into this box...
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div style="display:inline-block;margin:auto;min-width:33%;">
        <div style="border: 1px solid #aeaefb;">
            <div style="width:95%;margin:auto;border: 3px solid #9a244f;">
                    Content goes into this box...
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Yup, You can't align an element which is floating. Need to remove that float styling, and change to inline-block. but if you're using inline-block, please note that, it will have space between each element. refer to this for the solution https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Comment: @lavya R the answer is fine . but how the OP will control the things for mobile only using inline-css?

Comment: @SahilDhir  I hope this works for mobile too. But media queries can only be used if he is not using any email templates. Since he used inline styling, using media queries is not recommended.

Comment: @MarkJ99 Inline styling is not recommended unless there is no other way to use. If here inline styling is not needed, you can easily have control in mobile using media queries.

Comment: @LavyaR he has clearly mentioned that he is updating his site .. Using classes will be a flexible approach to fix the problem.Your solution doesnot work on desktop...

Answer (score 0):

> **Solution 1:** using Media queries

1. **First of all I have changed your inline-css to classes , so that you can easily control them with css.**
2. **Secondly I have use simple flexbox approach to solve the problem.**
3. **you need to use media query to control the css behaviour for mobile.**

> Here is the working code:

```css
.box{float:left;margin:auto;min-width:33%}
.section-boxes{width:50%;background-color:#dadada;padding:4px;border-radius:4px;overflow:hidden;}

@media(max-width:768px){
.section-boxes{text-align:center; display:flex; flex-direction:column;}
.box{width:100%;}

}
```

```html
<div class="section-boxes">

    <div class="box">
        <div style="border: 1px solid #aeaefb;">
            <div style="width:95%;margin:auto;border: 3px solid #9a244f;">
                    Content goes into this box...
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="box">
        <div style="border: 1px solid #aeaefb;">
            <div style="width:95%;margin:auto;border: 3px solid #9a244f;">
                    Content goes into this box...
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="box">
        <div style="border: 1px solid #aeaefb;">
            <div style="width:95%;margin:auto;border: 3px solid #9a244f;">
                    Content goes into this box...
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

> **Solution 2:** Using inline css

1. **Using display:inline-block on the box elements**
2. **Using calc() method to calculate the width of each box so it works both on mobile and desktop with one code.**

   > Here is the working code:

```html
<div style="width:50%;background-color:#dadada;padding:4px;border-radius:4px;overflow:hidden; text-align:center">

    <div style="display:inline-block;margin:0 auto;min-width:calc(33% - 8px);">
        <div style="border: 1px solid #aeaefb;">
            <div style="width:95%;margin:auto;border: 3px solid #9a244f;">
                    Content goes into this box...
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div style="display:inline-block;margin:0 auto;min-width:calc(33% - 8px);">
        <div style="border: 1px solid #aeaefb;">
            <div style="width:95%;margin:auto;border: 3px solid #9a244f;">
                    Content goes into this box...
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div style="display:inline-block;margin:0 auto;min-width:calc(33% - 8px);">
        <div style="border: 1px solid #aeaefb;">
            <div style="width:95%;margin:auto;border: 3px solid #9a244f;">
                    Content goes into this box...
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: @MarkJ99 I have given you 2 solutions 1 with media queries and other with inline css using vanila css calc() method.. Choose the best you want  :)

Comment: Some good suggestions, thanks. One thing missing though is the bit where I need the boxes to use up all of the container width (i.e. expand to 100% of the container) as each of the three boxes drop down. Otherwise the boxes remain stuck in the 33% width state and, when stacked on top of each other, they don't seem to adapt to the fact that they can now fill the left and right spaces.

Comment: @MarkJ99 then you have to use the media query solution as thats the only way to target a mobile browser to get 100% width.. I have updated my media query answer.. Do check that